# WTV playback speed in Windows Media Center

Tags: windows-media-center, matroska, video-playback, dvr-ms

Windows 7 saves TV recording in .wtv files. These files can be played in fast forward mode (1.5x or so speedup) in Windows Media Center.

Is this mode allowed only for WTV files or is due to codec capabilities?

Comment: This is two separate questions 1) re mode and 2) re convert - they will have separate answers - please ask them as separate questions

Comment: I removed your second question. Feel free to post it separately.